# How to show the image downloaded fom the firebase storage always in a flutter application statically,can be opened and viewed on a click

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage, imageurl

[image: My application screenshot]How to show  the image downloaded from the firebase storage always in a flutter  application statically, can be opened and viewed on a click.

I have already uploaded an image from camera and gallery to firebase storage. Now I want to download the image from the firebase storage and make a provision that the images downloaded will be readily stay in the application without disappearing.

I mean when ever user visits that flutter application screen, the image or images downloaded should be shown.

Uploaded the image using using firebase storage:

```
   final FirebaseStorage _storage =
  FirebaseStorage(storageBucket: 'gs://flutter-imageupload-cb66a.appspot.com');
      StorageUploadTask _uploadTask;
      _startUpload() async {
    String imagePath = 'DeviceImages/DeviceImage${DateTime.now()}.png';
    final StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage().ref().child(imagePath);
    final StorageUploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putFile(imageFile1);
    await uploadTask.onComplete;
    _addPathToDatabase(imagePath);
       print("Image uploaded");
    setState(() {
      _uploadTask =
          _storage.ref().child(imagePath).putFile(imageFile1);
    });
  }
```

used `firebase_storage: ^3.1.6`   and  `firebase_database:`

used  `image_picker: ^0.6.7+17`  for picking the image from camera and Gallery.

Comment: There are many answers online on how to get the image from firebase storage. For storing the images, I would recommend using CachedNetworkImage package. It will cache the image and store the images locally for 30 days. If you want to store the images permanently, you would have to save the images directly in the application directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To download an image from firebase storage, try the following:

```
final StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage().ref().child(imagePath);
final UploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putFile(imageFile1);
uploadTask.then((res) {
   res.ref.getDownloadURL();
});
```

`UploadTask` extends the `Future` class therefore you can use  `then()` which registers a callback which will be called after the future returns a result. Then you will be able to get the `url` using the method `getDownloadUrl()`.

Once you have the `url` you can use `CachedNetworkImage` class and do the following:

```
CachedNetworkImage(
  imageUrl: imgUrl,
);
```

You need to download the package first:

https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image

---

Check the guide here on how to display images from the internet:

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/images/network-image

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/images/cached-images

Comment: I tried using your code .Now I am seeing following errors                                                The method 'then' isn't defined for the type 'StorageUploadTask'.  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'then'. Open documentation  &  Undefined name 'imgUrl'.

Comment: check my edit. Regarding `imgUrl` this is a variable you have to create, you need to store the `res.ref.getDownloadURL();` inside this variable

Comment: My new code is as follows                                                                                                         
    final StorageReference storageReferencFirebaseStorage().ref().child(imagePath);
    final StorageUploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putFile(_imageFile1);
    uploadTask.then((res) {
      res.ref.getDownloadURL();
    });
    //Image.file(File(widget.imagePath)
  ;
    setState(() {
      _uploadTask =        _storage.ref().child(imagePath).putFile(_imageFile1);
    });
    CachedNetworkImage(
      imageUrl: imgUrl,
    );
  }

Comment: check my edit. Regarding `imgUrl` this is a variable you have to create, you need to store the `res.ref.getDownloadURL();` inside this variable

Comment: ok what about "The method 'then' isn't defined for the type 'StorageUploadTask'. "

Comment: check the edit in the answer I change the type from `StorageUploadTask` to `UploadTask`

Comment: upgrade firebase_storage to latest version

Comment: ok I will update you after upgrading to latest version

Comment: Now My dependancies are firebase_storage: ^5.2.0
  firebase_core: ^0.5.3   and new errors shown  are Undefined class 'StorageUploadTask'. and  Undefined class 'StorageReference'.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64764111/undefined-class-storagereference-when-using-firebase-storage

Comment: Ok all errors are fixed , I am running the App and checking whether images are cached or not . Thank you

Comment: In my application I have used firestore_service.dart using dependancy cloud_firestore: in another module  there    error shown at                  Stream<List<Entry>> getEntries(){
    return _db.collection('entries').snapshots().map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs.map((doc) => Entry.fromJson(doc)).toList());
  }
The argument type 'Map<String, dynamic> Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String,

Comment: After upgrading  the dependancies versions and doing changes in the code  My Application Widget or screen  showing balank white screen  I dont know why ?

Comment: Now I have changed to                                                                                                              
      final StorageReference ref  = FirebaseStorage().ref().child      imagePath);
    final StorageUploadTask uploadTask2 = ref.putFile(_imageFile1);
    final link = await ref.getDownloadURL();
    await Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(    text: link,
    ));
  );
    setState(() {
      _uploadTask2 =
          _storage2.ref().child(imagePath).putFile(_imageFile2);
    });
    var imgUrl;
    CachedNetworkImage(
      imageUrl: imgUrl,
    );
  }

Comment: finally I have used the codeas above but my image is not showing static in the application. Please fix my issue.

Comment: I still did not achieved catching imageUrls and showing static images. Please help

Comment: In my application there is a requirement of total 3 images  and two PDFS to upload to firebase storage  and then download again back in the flutter application. Now I want  to build my application in such a way that  user should be able to open each form page and vie or open the images andpdfs in the form page itself. Hence I want o use caching of imagesUrls and PDFUrls. So please help me fix this issue.

Comment: Already I have succesfully uploaded all of them and able to download or view except PDF file.  I have retrieved  all the downloadedUrls  for all of them

Comment: Please some body fix my issue , I want to set the images and pdfs  in the application permanently  until deletion.

Comment: if you save the images and pdfs in firebase storage which is done in this answer, then you will always see them in your application

Comment: Yes I am seeing them perfectly  as I am using image_picker and file_picker and setting them  to image or file. But my issue is I want to set the images permanently  in the application so that when ever I open the same form page the text and images and pdfs should be visible or  enabled  to clickable and opened

Comment: arent u saving them in firebase storage, all you have to do is retrieve them from there. They are permanently in the storage so just retrieve, has nothing to do with image_picker or file_picker

Comment: My Application consist of Grid View with images, each image when clicked leads to a form page for user submission of text data , images , pdfs uploading etc. When user once submit all the data, data is saved into firebase. Again when the user opens the same form page for the second time , all the text data saved should be shown , images and pdfs should be clicked and opened

Comment: so then I have to see that every time I open that particular form page , those images and pdfs contained should show in the form page.

Comment: Please ask a different question and be clear with what you want

Comment: I want to upload images, text data and pdfs to firebase data base and storage and retrieve all of them . Please guide.

Comment: User enters text data , uploads images, uploads pdfs and submits the form. after submission  user should be able to retrieve all the data in the different page/ screen.

Comment: Peter Haddad I have updated the screenshot for your understanding. Please fix my issue.

Comment: Peter Haddad I have updated the screenshot for your understanding. Please fix my issue

Comment: Please somebody fix my issue .I have clearly provided my screenshot or idea of the Application. Atleast help me retrieve pdf with the help of pdf url. I already recieved the uploaded pdf url.